# How can I search for a string and return a numeric value to C++?

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to use Python with C++ in order to read a text file and search that text file for the specific input received from C++ (a string value) It should then return a numeric value of the string frequency in that text file back to the C++ code. As the code is, it only returns "1" on the display of my program. Any tips?

```
def ItemFreq(v):
    #Opening and reading the input item list file
    file = open("ItemList.txt", "r") 
    text = file.read()
    #Output our list in a new line format
    word_list = text.split('\n')
    #Declare an empty dictionary
    word_freq = {}
    for word in word_list:
        word_freq[word] = word_freq.get(word, 0) + 1
    if v in word_freq:
        return word_freq[v]
    else:
        return 0
```

CPP portion with the user input prompt

```
        // Option 2 for our specific item purchase information
        else if (a == 2) {
            int v;
            cout << "Please enter the name of an item to begin search: ";
            cin >> v;
            // Print our returned input from Python
            cout << callIntFunc("ItemFreq", v) << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
```

And the Python integration in my CPP file

```
int callIntFunc(string proc, string param)
{
    char *procname = new char[proc.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, proc.c_str());

    char *paramval = new char[param.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(paramval, param.c_str());


    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue = nullptr, *presult = nullptr;
    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();
    // Build the name object
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"PythonCode");
    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    // pDict is a borrowed reference 
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, procname);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        pValue = Py_BuildValue("(z)", paramval);
        PyErr_Print();
        presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    //printf("Result is %d\n", _PyLong_AsInt(presult));
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    // Clean up
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    // clean 
    delete[] procname;
    delete[] paramval;


    return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);
}

int callIntFunc(string proc, int param)
{
    char *procname = new char[proc.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, proc.c_str());

    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue = nullptr, *presult = nullptr;
    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();
    // Build the name object
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"PythonCode");
    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    // pDict is a borrowed reference 
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, procname);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        pValue = Py_BuildValue("(i)", param);
        PyErr_Print();
        presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    //printf("Result is %d\n", _PyLong_AsInt(presult));
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    // Clean up
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    // clean 
    delete[] procname;

    return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);
}
```

Comment: Maybe return the dictionary itself and not just the frequency. Is Cpp reading from console text?

Comment: That aside, you know that if you do all of this in Cpp, it will be way faster and straightforward.

Comment: @Goion Unfortunately this is for a school assignment that requires python and C++, with these specific instructions. I've updated my post to include the relevant cpp information. Let me know what you think

Comment: Your `return` statement should be `return word_freq[v]`, and it should be out-indented one tab.  Right now, you return on the first word you find, so the value is always 1.

Comment: @TimRoberts I've changed the return statement and out-indented one tab as mentioned, however my program now throws an exception at the return line. I noticed in the program itself that it says `KeyError: 0`. I'm still learning VSC, so hopefully I'm explaining this correctly, but there is a red error symbol next to the line `return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);` with the thrown exception info.

Comment: Well, you probably should be checking whether the parameter (`v`) is actually in the list at all.  `if v in word_freq:` / `return word_freq[v]` / `else:` / `return 0`.

Comment: @TimRoberts That's a good idea! I updated my question with that change, and it seems that the program returns 0 regardless of what I input.

Comment: Well, hang on a danged moment.  Your C++ function is passing an integer.  Integers are not words, and you are unlikely to find 7 in a list of words.  What is it you think this code is doing?

Comment: @TimRoberts How embarrassing! I though that my C++ code was using the callIntFunc to pass input v to Python. I was completely overlooking the fact that I wrote ```int v;``` instead of string. I've changed it and the code works as it should. Thank you very much for the help with this. I truly appreciate it!